# How to get tkinter scroll bar working (greyed out)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am creating a simple tkinter application. When the user presses a button an image appears. If they press it again another image appears etc. So I am wanting a scroll bar so that the user can scroll to the images that appear off the page. I am not sure what I have done wrong but the scroll bar is greyed out and is not working.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')


x = 30
y = 30
box_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='apple.png')



### SCROLL BAR ###

# create a main frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

# create a canvas
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

# add a scrollbar to the canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

# create Another frame inside the canvas
second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)

# add that new frame to a window in the canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw", width="10000")

def display():
    global x , y
    panel2 = tk.Label(main_frame, image=box_image, bg='#f7f6f6')
    panel2.place(x=x, y=y) 
    x = x
    y = y+200


button = tk.Button(second_frame, text="click me", command=display)
button.place(x=0, y=0)

label = tk.Label(second_frame, text="label", bg="blue")
label.pack(fill="x", padx=50)

new_frame = tk.Frame(second_frame, bg='black', height=110)
new_frame.pack(fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the image in `second_frame`, not in `main_frame`.

Comment: OP is using `place()` on the image label `panel2`, so it won't change the size of `second_frame` even though it is used instead of `main_frame`.  Since the `scrollregion` will not be updated, the scrollbar is still not working.

Comment: Yes when I change it to `second_frame` the image gets cut off and the scroll bar is still not working.

Comment: Please help me, this answer was not a solution